# mysqlfrm redirect to text file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to recover create statement from mysql frm files using mysqlfrm utility.
Is there any way to redirect output of the utility to text file in the windows environment.
I tried using  the redirection ">" syntax but it is not working.

I am using the following command

```
mysqlfrm --server=root:pasword@localhost "c:\mysql\data\data\db\table1.frm" --port=3308
```

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL Utilities Console:

`mysqluc> mysqlfrm --server=user:pwd@localhost --port=3307 "path_to_db_folder" > "path_to_file"`

Change with your settings.
It worked for me.